# LZ4HC Compile problem: LZ4_compressBound undefined

Tags: compiler-errors, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking, lz4

I tried to create an executable file for LZ4HC (I used the source code from lz4 homepage), but when I was trying to execute the file, it displayed "Symbol error LZ4_compressBound undefined".
Neither static linking nor dynamical linking wasn't worked.

```
gcc -shared -ggdb3 -fPIC -o lz4hc.h lz4hc.c
```

or

```
gcc -c lz4hc.c -o lz4hc.o
ar rcs lz4hc.a lz4hc.o
```

Why the symbol LZ4_compressBound is undefined after the linking?

Comment: "Why ... after the linking?" -- Please edit your question and show the actual *link* command.

Answer (score 0):

> Neither static linking nor dynamical linking wasn't worked.
>
> `gcc -shared -ggdb3 -fPIC -o lz4hc.h lz4hc.c`

Above command complies `lz4hc.c` into a shared library named `lz4hc.h`. That is almost surely *not* what you wanted.

> `gcc -c lz4hc.c -o lz4hc.o`
> `ar rcs lz4hc.a lz4hc.o`

These command produce `lz4hc.a` (correctly) but do not perform any actual linking.

I am guessing that your actual link command looks something like `gcc lz4hc.a main.o`, in which case your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8380087/50617) (among 100s of other duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

`LZ4_compressBound()` is defined within `lz4.c`.

The documentation states that, in order to use/link `lz4hc`, one also needs `lz4` :
https://github.com/lz4/lz4/tree/dev/lib#high-compression-variant